# How can i assign a value of a variable from another variable?

Tags: c

i am trying variable one = variable two; it does not work.

the code is in portuguese so it maybe hard to read.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void){

    int ano, mes, dia;
    int dm[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    printf("digite um ano: ");
    scanf("%d", &ano);

    if(ano %4==0 || ano %100 == 0 || ano %400 == 0){

        ano=0;
    }
    else{

        ano = 1;
    }

    printf("digite um mes: ");
    scanf("%d", &mes);

    mes = dm;

    printf("%d", mes);





return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mes` is an integer (`int`). Your `scanf("%d", &mes)` reads an integer from the user and stores it in `mes`. But then the next statement `mes = dm` overwrites that value of `mes` with the value of `dm` which happens to be of type  `int[]` (array of integer). I assume you saw a warning from your compiler about incompatible types? Regardless, you're overwriting what you just read from the user. It's unclear what your intention is with that part of the code.

Comment: Just an aside, are you trying to determine if `ano` represents a leap year with `if(ano %4==0 || ano %100 == 0 || ano %400 == 0)`? If so, that's not quite the correct rule. It should be `if ((ano % 4 == 0) && ((ano % 100 != 0) || (ano % 400 == 0)))`. In either case, it's unclear why you are rewriting the value of the year `ano` to a 0 or a 1.

Comment: Re "*it's unclear why you are rewriting the value of the year ano to a 0 or a 1.*", Well, it's clear, just wrong :) Instead of repurposing `ano`, a new appropriately-named variable should be used.

Comment: im trying to print a monthly calendar the ano variable is going to be used on the future so the code aint ready yet, the ano variable is goint to be used to see if the year its a leap year or not, 0 to leap year 1 to not leap year. ano = year mes= month dia= day

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question: Which assignment in the source shown does not work for you? What do you expect, and what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you assign an array into an integer!
mes is an integer (int) and dm is an array (int[] -array of integer)

Comment: Not at all. In fact, one _can't_ assign an array to integer in C. What actually happens here is the name `dm` of an `int[]` array decays to a pointer `(int *)` to the first item of the array, like in the expression `&dm[0]`, and then that pointer is implicitly converted to `int` (which may or may not succeed, and the compiler should issue an appropriate warning if the conversion is not safe).